# Efficient sampling of factor variable from dataframe subsets

Tags: r, vectorization, lapply, sample

I have a dataframe `df1` which contains 6 columns, two of which (`var1` & `var3`) I am using to `split` `df1` by, resulting in a list of dataframes `ls1`.

For each sub dataframe in `ls1` I want to `sample()` `x$var2`, `x$num` times with `x$probs` probabilities as follows:

Create data:

```
var1 <- rep(LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 3 )], each = 6)
var2 <- rep(LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 3 )], 6)
var3 <- rep(1:2,3, each = 3)
num <- rep(c(10, 11, 13, 8, 20, 5), each = 3)
probs <- round(runif(18), 2)
df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(var1, var2, var3, num, probs))
ls1 <- split(df1, list(df1$var1, df1$var3))
```

have a look at the first couple list elements:

```
$A.1
  var1 var2 var3 num probs
1    A    A    1  10  0.06
2    A    B    1  10  0.27
3    A    C    1  10  0.23

$B.1
  var1 var2 var3 num probs
7    B    A    1  13  0.93
8    B    B    1  13  0.36
9    B    C    1  13  0.04
```

`lapply` over `ls1`:

```
ls1 <- lapply(ls1, function(x) { 
  res <- table(sample(x$var2, size = as.numeric(as.character(x$num)), 
    replace = TRUE, prob = as.numeric(as.character(x$probs))))
  res <- as.data.frame(res)
  cbind(x, res = res$Freq)
})
df2 <- do.call("rbind", ls1)
df2
```

Have a look at the first couple list elements of the result:

```
$A.1
  var1 var2 var3 num probs res
1    A    A    1  10  0.06   2
2    A    B    1  10  0.27   4
3    A    C    1  10  0.23   4

$B.1
  var1 var2 var3 num probs res
7    B    A    1  13  0.93  10
8    B    B    1  13  0.36   3
9    B    C    1  13  0.04   0
```

So for each dataframe a new variable `res` is created, the sum of `res` equals `num` and the elements of `var2` are represented in `res` in proportions relating to `probs`. This does what I want but it becomes very slow when there is a lot of data.

**My Question:** is there a way to replace the `lapply` piece of code with something more efficient/faster?

I am just beginning to learn about vectorization and am guessing this could be vectorized? but I am unsure of how to achieve it.

`ls1` is eventually returned to a dataframe structure so if it doesn't need to become a list to begin with all the better (although it doesn't really matter how the data is structured for this step).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide code that generates a big data set so we could benchmark possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should create df1 using data.frame() rather than converting from a matrix, because the matrix forces all data types to the be the same even though you have both numeric and character variables.

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3, num, probs)
```

Next, instead of using the `sample` function, the `rmultinom` function is much more efficient because it directly outputs the number of draws for each value in x$var2:

```
ls1 <- lapply(ls1, function(x) { 
    x$res <- rmultinom(1, x$num[1], x$probs)
    x
})
```

This should be noticeably faster than using the `sample` approach.

Comment: Thanks, this resulted in the runtime decreasing by ~1.5 orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than splitting your data frame in groups, I would use package {dplyr} with a group_by+mutate:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate_at(vars(num, probs), as.numeric) %>%
  group_by(var1, var3) %>%
  mutate(res = c(rmultinom(1, num[1], probs)))
```

This should be fast and you can keep the original data structure.

Learn more [there](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#grouped-mutates-and-filters).